# Saving int from SQL Server database to c# variable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm very new to C# but I need to save the results of two columns (`balance` & `withdraw`) from a SQL Server database table to C# variables. I have read that you should use `SqlDataReader` then other things are saying not to and use `ExecuteScalar` and I'm getting really confused with it all.

Here is the code I have to far. Any help is appreciated thanks.

```
private void subwithdraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Student04\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ATMdata;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Command String", con);
    SqlDataReader rdr = null;

    try
    {
        using (var check_balance = con.CreateCommand())
        using (var edit_balance = con.CreateCommand())
        using (var edit_withdraw = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            check_balance.CommandText = @"select Balance, Withdraw 
                                          from Cust_details 
                                          Where Account_num ='" + show.AccNo + "'  ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Judging from your database name ATMData, security would be an issue (also if you're a student). Your query is vulnarable to SQL Injection, you should use parameterized queries.

Comment: What are the type of your `Balance` and `Withdraw` columns?

Comment: thanks ill have a read on parameterized queries and both of the columns are integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *assume* your query return one row, you can generate them with using [`ExecuteReader` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as;

```
using(var rdr = check_balance.ExecuteReader())
{
   while(rdr.Read())
   {
       int balance = rdr.GetInt32(0);
       int withdraw= rdr.GetInt32(1);
   }
}
```

`ExecuteScalar` wouldn't fit for your case since it returns first column of the first row of your query. Other columns are ignored.

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.